# Get element 'id' when clicked, then activate corresponding 'sibling'. JS & Django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, django

I am working on a Django website where customers can book mobile barbers for appointments in their own home. All the barbers in our model 'BarberProfile' are visible on our /barbers page (image below). Each barber has a profile image with a left and right arrow on either side. When these arrows are clicked, I want the specific barber's haircut demo images to appear instead of their profile image, essentially an 'image slider'.

I have successfully made an image slider using the JS code below (profile.js). But, I'm now having this problem:

- How do I prevent other barber's image sliders being activated when a specific barber's arrows are clicked? When a specific profiles arrows are clicked I only want the corresponding image slider to activate.

I'm almost 100% sure the solution lies in giving each set of arrows, and each slider a unique 'id'. So, I gave the arrows and images these id's:

```
id="arrow-left-{{BarberProfile.id}}"
id="arrow-right-{{BarberProfile.id}}"

id="slide-{{BarberProfile.id}}"
```

I also managed to get an elements 'id' onclick, but I am unsure how to pass this into the 'let' document.querySelector, or if this is even the right thing to do.

```
function printID(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e = e.target || e.srcElement;
    console.log("ID: " + e.id);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

profile.js

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
    arrowLeft = document.querySelector(".arrow-left"),
    arrowRight = document.querySelector(".arrow-right"),
    current = 0;

//clear all images
function reset(){
    for(let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++){
        sliderImages[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

//initialises slider
function startSlide(){
    reset();
    sliderImages[0].style.display = 'block';
}

//show prev
function slideLeft(){
    reset();
    sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = 'block';
    current--;
}

//show next
function slideRight(){
    reset();
    sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = 'block';
    current++;
}

//left arrow clicked
arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(current === 0){
        current = sliderImages.length;
    }
    slideLeft();
});

//right arrow clicked
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(current === sliderImages.length - 1){
        current = - 1;
    }
    slideRight();
});

startSlide();
```

profile.html

```
{% for BarberProfile in queryset_list %}

    <div onclick="printID(this.id);"> <!-- for JS on click id identification -->
        <div id="total-div" class="margin-left-1 margin-right-1 margin-top-2 margin-bottom-2">

            <div style="width:50%;position:absolute;left: 50%;transform: translateX(-50%);z-index:1;pointer-events: none">
                <div style="padding-top: 100%;">
                    <img id="arrow-left-{{BarberProfile.id}}" class="arrow-left" style="pointer-events: auto;" src="{% static "img/arrow-2.svg" %}" alt="Mobile menu arrow">
                    <img id="arrow-right-{{BarberProfile.id}}" class="arrow-right" style="pointer-events: auto;" src="{% static "img/arrow-2.svg" %}" alt="Mobile menu arrow">
                </div>
            </div>


            <a class="profile-div" id="{{BarberProfile.id}} profile-div" target="{{BarberProfile.booking_link}}" onClick="toggle_content(this.id)">

                <!-- images -->
                <div id="slide-{{BarberProfile.id}}" class="image slide slide1 border-radius-2 shadow" style="background-image: url({{BarberProfile.image.url}})">
                    <div id="image-structure"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="slide-{{BarberProfile.id}}" class="image slide slide2 border-radius-2 shadow" style="background-image: url({{BarberProfile.image_1.url}})">
                    <div id="image-structure"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="slide-{{BarberProfile.id}}" class="image slide slide3 border-radius-2 shadow" style="background-image: url({{BarberProfile.image_2.url}})">
                    <div id="image-structure"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- images -->

                <h4 class="color-1 margin-top-2-lh margin-bottom-2-lh">{{BarberProfile.first_name}} {{BarberProfile.last_name}}</h4>
                <p class="color-4"> {{BarberProfile.bio}} </p>
                <div>
                    <div id="text-div">
                        <img id="text-image" class="margin-top-2" src="{% static "img/experience.svg" %}" alt="Mobile barber or hairdresser experience icon">
                        <p id="text" class="color-4 margin-top-2">{{BarberProfile.years_of_experience}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div id="text-div">
                        <img id="text-image" class="margin-top-1" src="{% static "img/scissors.svg" %}" alt="Mobile barber or hairdresser experience icon">
                        <p id="text" class="color-4 margin-top-1">{{BarberProfile.types}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example using django 2 and foundation UI.  The foundation UI framework implementation can be ignored and the app.js function can be moved to a script tag in products.html if you want to make it less cluttered with my implementation details/setup.

products.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
{% for product in products %}

  <li class="accordion-item is-active" data-accordion-item>
      <!-- Accordion tab title -->
      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">
        <span class="line-heading">Name:</span> {{ product.name }}
        <span class="line-heading">Price:</span> {{ product.price }}
        <span class="line-heading">Total Cumulative Donations: </span> {{ product.total_amount_paid }}
        <span class="line-heading">Feature Area:</span> {{ product.product_area }}
      </a>

      <!-- Accordion tab content: it would start in the open state due to using the `is-active` state class. -->
      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
        <table class="stack product-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="test1234">
                <div data-id="{{product.id}}" class="image-detail" onclick="toggleFullSize(this)">
                  <img class="thumbnail-image-line-detail" src="url('{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ product.image }}">
                </div>
                <div class="detail-paragraph">
                  <font class="description-heading">Description</font>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <font class="description-text">{{ product.description }}</font>
                </div>
              </td>


              <td>
                <p></p>
                <form method="post" action="{% url 'add_to_cart' product.id %}">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <fieldset class="fieldset" style="background-color:grey border">
                    <legend>Donate to fund work</legend>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input name='quantity' type="number" min="1" max="999" class="form-control input-group-field" placeholder="Quantity">
                      <div class="input-group-button">
                        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
                </form>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  </li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<html class="no-js">

<head>
    <title>{% block page_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/foundation.css' %}" type='text/css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}" type='text/css' />
</head>

<body>
    <h1>
        {% block page_heading %}{% endblock %}
    </h1>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li class="navigation-link"><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-link"><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-link"><a href="{% url 'products' %}">Features & Issues</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li class="navigation-link"><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-link"><a href="{% url 'registration' %}">Register</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-link"><a href="{% url 'products' %}">Features & Issues</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <hr> {% if messages %}
    <div>
        {% for message in messages %} {{ message }} {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %} {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    <script src="{% static 'js/vendor/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/vendor/foundation.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/vendor/what-input.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js (the first line initializes the foundation page elements)

```
$(document).foundation()

function toggleFullSize(element){
  element.classList.toggle('image-detail-full-size');
  // alert(element.childNodes[1].className);
  alert(element.parentNode.childNodes[3].className);
}
```

The function is taking the element that triggered the click, finding the parent, then collecting the children of the parent and getting the class name of the next div in my case but you could toggle the disabled flag in your case

```
element.parentNode.childNodes[3].disabled = true;
```

taken from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp)